# Вызов функции в javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

есть ли в js возможность сделать функцию и сразу её вызвать? Я знаю что так можно делать с анонимными функциями, но их нужно чему-то присваивать. А можно ли без присваивания?

Я пытался сделать так:

```js
(function () {
 //smth
}());
```

Не получилось. Какие ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(function () {
    //smth
})();
```

Вот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) про IIFE

Comment: Просто не там скобки поставили